# creating links dynamically jquery mobile in a loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, each

consider this json Object:

```
[{"data":{"ID":"3","Category":"Career"}},{"data":{"ID":"5","Category":"Emotions"}},{"data":{"ID":"1","Category":"Finance"}},{"data":{"ID":"2","Category":"Health"}},{"data":{"ID":"6","Category":"Legacy"}},{"data":{"ID":"4","Category":"Relationships"}}]
```

and consider this client code:

```
$(function (){ 

 $.ajax({                                      
  url: 'category.php',                         
  data: "",                        
   dataType: 'json',                      
  success: function(data)         
  {
     var output = '';
      $.each( data, function( key, obj) {
      $.each( obj, function( index, item) {
        //console.log(index+ ": " + item);
        url = "goal.php?catID=" + item.ID;
        output = '<li><a>' + item.Category+ '</a></li>';
        href = $('a').attr("href",url); $('a').append(href);
        $('#listview').append(output).listview('refresh');
       });
   });
   } 
});  });
```

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
<div data-role="header"><h1>My Goals</h1></div>

<div data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true">
  <ul data-role="listview" id="listview">    
  </ul>
</div>
```

My first attempt in JQuery mobile and I am trying to loop over the JSON and output the categories with their links -

I am almost succeeding but it is only appending the last record item.ID on the url?

Can somebody please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(function (){ 

    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'category.php',                         
        data: "",                        
        dataType: 'json',                      
        success: function(data)         
        {
            $.each( data, function( key, obj) {
                var item = obj.data;
                $('<li></li>').append($('<a></a>', {
                    text: item.Category,
                    href: 'goal.php?catID=' + item.ID
                })).appendTo( $('#listview'))
            });

            $('#listview').listview('refresh');
        } 
    });  
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qtGNJ/)

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
$('a').attr("href",url)
```

You're changing all the `a` elements of your page. And the last iteration wins of course.

I'd suggest you this in your loop :

```
$('#listview').append(
    $('<li/>').append($('</a>').attr('href', url).html(url))
).listview('refresh');
```

Comment: Thanks - this solution could work and pointed out where I was going wrong but the second one from Arun P Johny was clearer, hence the accept.